# Making a two row table header in HTML

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to set up a table to have a header that is two rows.  On the top row, there will be an input box to allow the user to filter the table.  On the second will be the column names.  So far, the closest I'm able to get is this:

```
<thead>
    <tr class="bg-primary">
        <th colspan="5">
            <input id="searchBox" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by name">
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-primary text-white">
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Street Address</th>
        <th scope="col">City</th>
        <th scope="col">State</th>
        <th scope="col">Phone</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

However, so far I've been unable to find a way to get rid of the white border between the two rows.  I want this to look like one header, so I'm trying to find a way to either make the two rows overlap or have the border between them be the same color as bg-primary.  So far I've had no luck in either.  I'm using red to style the bottom and top borders, but they do not show up in the page:

```
<thead>
        <tr class="bg-primary" style="border-bottom-color: #9d063b">
            <th colspan="5">
                <input id="searchBox" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by name">
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bg-primary text-white" style="border-bottom-color: #9d063b">
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Street Address</th>
            <th scope="col">City</th>
            <th scope="col">State</th>
            <th scope="col">Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

And I have not found any information on either merging the two, or having one overlap the other.

Comment: try to create a fiddle then put the link here so we can see your problem

Comment: Try this attributes on the table: <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> Or in css put this on the table: border-spacing: 0;  border-collapse: collapse;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, even you put `border-bottom-color` style on the rows, it wouldn't show up on the page because bootstrap puts top and bottom borders on `<th>` and `<td>` instead of `<tr>`.

If you move the border bottom color to the `<th>`s:

```
<tr class="bg-primary">
    <th colspan="5"  style="border-bottom-color: #9d063b;">
        <input id="searchBox" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by name">
    </th>
</tr>
```

You will see the bottom borders in red:

[image]

Anyway, that's not related to your problem nor what you try to accomplish.

### 1. Use CSS

There are many ways to get what you want, but the easily way is just to get rid of the top and bottom borders via CSS.

#### CSS

```
.table thead td,
.table thead th {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

#### Result

[image]

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/258054/

### 2. Bootstrap border utility class

You can also use bootstrap utility class to remove the borders: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/

#### HTML

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-primary">
            <th colspan="5" class="border-bottom-0">
                <input id="searchBox" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by name">
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bg-primary text-white">
            <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">Name</th>
            <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">Street Address</th>
            <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">City</th>
            <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">State</th>
            <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/258060/